# TCP Keep Alive in windows is running but the program is not affected for Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure-resource-manager, keep-alive, azure-sql-server, tcp-keepalive

To keep Azure SQL alive MS have provided [this workaround](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-to-an-azure-sql-database) , After following this workaround the keep alive messages are sent I traced over wireshark .

But still my application is facing Connection Reset after 30 minutes ..

I have made a normal connection to azure using jdbc libs provided by microsoft. my connection uri is :

```
jdbc:sqlserver://server.database.windows.net:1433;database=dbsample;user=username;password=abcd;encrypt=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;socketKeepAlive=true
```

Can someone throw some spark over this ?

Comment: Long lived tcp connections over the internet never last long, Microsoft are clear in their advice that you need to build in resiliency and expect connection failures - build retries into your application :)

Comment: Well Thanks for your reply . Building retries in the application is the last trump card move as it requires application testing flow again . I am expecting a workaround without any change in application , Since Microsoft provided the workaround I beleived in it . But still my issue persists .

Comment: I thought you might say that which is why just a comment and not an answer :), I honestly wish you the best of luck with it but from experience, adding a cloud service to an application requires some re-writing otherwise you end up with things like this. Maybe someone else knows of a 30 min sql db timeout.

Comment: Thanks @EdElliott . will try my best to sort it out .